# adding DataFrame column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I obtain Pandas datafrane df_merged by filtering df_upper and df_lower for the same entries in index, column 'call/put' and column 'expiration'

```
 df_merged = df_upper[
     (df_upper.index.isin(df_lower.index)) & 
     (df_upper['call/put'].isin(df_lower['call/put'])) &         
     (df_upper['expiration'].isin(df_lower['expiration'])) 
 ]
```

Now I want to add a column called 'lower ask' to df_merged by inserting values from df_lower that have the same values in index, column 'call/put' and column 'expiration' as df_merged. I use the follwing code:

```
df_merged['lower ask'] = df_lower['ask'][
     (df_lower.index.isin(df_merged.index)) &  
     (df_lower['call/put'].isin(df_merged['call/put'])) & 
     (df_lower['expiration'].isin(df_merged['expiration'])) 
]
```

This obviously never comes to an end, although the first line of code for obtaining df_merged was executed quite fast. Length of df_merged is 337548 lines, length of df_lower is 341011 lines. Is there a bug in my code or is there another reason for the huge computation speed difference between those two lines of code?

Here is a data sample:

Here is a sample of df_merged:

```
np.random.seed(1)
n=330000 
df_merged = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=n))
df_merged.columns = ['strike']
df_merged['bid'] = np.random.randn(n)
df_merged['ask'] =np.random.randn(n)
df_merged['call/put'] = np.random.choice(['put','call'], n)
df_merged['expiration'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2001', periods=n)
```

Here is a sample of df_lower:

```
df_lower=df_merged.copy()
df_lower=df_lower.append(df_lower.iloc[10:11,0:5])
df_lower.iloc[330000:330001,4:5]=5
```

df_lower and df_merged are quite similar, however, one line in the sample has other value combination in index, column call/put and expiration. That one has to be filtered out and the values of ask in df_lower that have matches in index, column call/put and expiration have to be added to the corresponding row in df_merged in a new column called 'lower-ask'.

call put column contains eighter string "call" or "put". I did df_lower.iloc[330000:330001,4:5]=5 just to show that df_merged and df_lower ar not exactly the same. df_upper has the same format as df_merged and df_lower. df_merged contains rows which have same combination of expiration, index and call/put both in df_lower and df_upper plus values of bid and ask in df_upper. Now I want to add to df_merged the values of bid and ask of df_lower that correspond to rows with same combination of index, expiration and call/put in df_merged. When I tried pandas.merge I got memory error, so I try to find a less computational expensive way. My stackoverflowish problem is indeed a bit absurd, however; i'm running a rather old machine and 4GB RAM. When I still run WinXp I had the same probelm, it didn't change after upgrading to Win7.

Comment: You should probably just join the dataframes. It'll be really hard to test possible solutions without a subset of representative data.

Comment: I just added a data sample.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you setting the `call/put` and `expiration` columns to integer values? Can't you make an example with like, 10 rows and construct the output you expect? That way we'll have a target to shoot for. `n = 330000` is pretty absurd for stack overflow.

Comment: Also, what does df_upper look like?

Comment: just added some comments...

Comment: please just make this a human-readable example with ~10 rows and some desired output. once we figure out what operations you really need, then we can tackle performance and scaling issues.

Comment: Just replace n=330000  by n=11.

Comment: your homework isn't done. still need to show `df_upper` and what the desired output is.